# Primary key error Vs select Command

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, query-optimization

i am creating a application as URL Counter.
i have created a table to store url and its count.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblurlcounter](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [type] [varchar](500) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [count] [bigint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblurlcounter] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

i have created a stored procedure to insert/update url in table. 
means when ever a value "URL" will be inserted in that table using stored procedure then i check that if its exists then update its count and if not then insert it in table with count=1.

my stored procedure is like:

```
declare @count int

select @count= [count] from tblurlcounter where [type] = @type
if @count > 0
begin
update tblurlcounter set [count]=@count + 1 where [type] = @type
select @count + 1

end
else 
begin
INSERT INTO [dbcounter].[dbo].[tblurlcounter]
           ([type]
           ,[count])
     VALUES
           (@type
           ,1)
end
```

this application will get around 80,000 to 100,000 hits in a minutes. so i want that my stored procedure should perform operation with good speed. i mean my solution should be optimized.

some one suggested me to change in my table and create its filed named "type" (which i am using to store url) as a primary key and in stored procedure i should first try to insert record and if its throw an error then check for error in next line and perform update operation.

so i am confused that which one will be faster, the primary key error apporach or i should go with select query and base on select's result i should perform insert/update operation

Now i need experts advice that, which approach is correct and if any other good approach is available then please suggest me.

thanks

Comment: Your code currently has a race condition (without using a transaction and using stronger isolation than the default): two executions could both observe a count of 0, and thus attempt the insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that load you'll need to be a bit clever. I've posted before on this

Basically, don't test first: try the INSERT. If it fails, run an update

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A27535+JFDI

Comment: @gbn: as my filed named "type" is of 500 in length. should i make it primary key or not?

Comment: 500 might be to large for an index, maybe create another column which hold the hashed value of the type column and index that?

Comment: @Magnus - max bytes per index key = 900, and it's varchar, not nvarchar, so it should be fine.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever wouldn't the fragmentation be huge if having a clustered index of that size?

Comment: @Magnus - I wouldn't recommend it for a *clustered* index, no.

Answer (score 2):

You can just try and do the update, if it doesn't exist no rows will be updated which you can check with [`@@rowcount`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx). If none are then you can add it otherwise the value is already incremented. You don't need the `@count` variable as then you would have to lock the row so nothing can change the value after you'd assigned it but before you updated the table.

```
update tblurlcounter set [count] = [count] + 1 where [type] = @type

if @@rowcount = 0 
begin
  insert into tblurlcounter 
  ([type],[count])
  values
  (@type, 1)
end
```

Comment: This also suffers from a similar race to that I noted in my comment - two executions could run the update when type doesn't exist, and then both attempt the insert.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach will not work properly as you're executing multiple statements. Ie, between this line happening :

```
select @count = [count] from tblurlcounter where [type] = @type
```

and either your INSERT or UPDATE actually executing, a separate execution of the stored procedure could also be adding a row, so you could end up with two INSERTS occurring almost simultaneously.

Instead, try this :

```
INSERT INTO [dbcounter].[dbo].[tblurlcounter]
           ([type]
           ,[count])
     VALUES
           (@type
           ,0)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(select 1 from tblurlcounter where [type] = @type)

UPDATE tblurlcounter SET [count]=[count] + 1 where [type] = @type
```

This will add a new row if a matching one isn't already present, combining the INSERT with the existence check. The update statement can be run secure in the knowledge that there is already a row to be updated.

You also really need an index on your Type column.

Comment: Your solution requires two lookups when only one is needed. But I agree on the Index of the Type column

Comment: Insert then Update are the right order to avoid the race. I'd probably insert `(@type,1)` and exit if `@@ROWCOUNT=1` after the insert, but other than that, this seems the best for a 2005 solution.

Answer (score -1):

This article explains very well the if exists update vs the update if not exists insert approach.

Apparently because of table locks, it's less expensive to do a select to check if it exists first. That way we avoid using an update, which would lock far more data than a select.

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/07/30/60273.aspx

also,

you can use:

if exists (select * from tblurlcounter where [type] = @type)

Comment: If your primary key also is your clustering key (which it is by default), this is a horrible idea for two main reasons: the `type` column is both variable width (bad for a clustering key), and much too wide. Furthermore, the `type` column might change - really bad idea for a primary key, too!